# image positions on jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Hello Friends I have a [website](http://www.boltonclinics.com/). In this I want the logo image will be like same on home page but in other pages it will be go towards the up and only the name will be seen not the whole logo image. So how to do that in jQuery? Any advice will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Can you give us some idea of how you want this to look? I'd like to try and help, but I can't work out what you want...or where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use javascript, just change it from `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`. (If IE <7 support is needed, there's workarounds for bugs in position:fixed).

**UPDATE (See Comments)**

Based on my understanding of what you're trying to accomplish from the comment string below, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.menu li a').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
        $('#logo').css('top', $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top);
        setTimeout("$('#logo').fadeIn('slow');", 600);
        });
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
            $(this).click();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ya I can give positions to it but as all the pages are within the single page it can't be done. Just check the site.

Comment: I checked the site... Changing `body #logo` from `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;`, when I clicked to another page, the logo stays stationary and the page slides to the corresponding "section". Is that not what you're describing?

Comment: actually I want that when I will click other buttons the logo will animate towards top position and will be fix in other pages except home page.

Comment: As @lukiffer says: http://www.csspivot.com/zPL5e Only bad thing about `position: fixed;` is that in mobile devices it works much like `position: absolute;` - So you dont want to show logo in the page that is the starting page for most visitors?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking for, but if I understand it correctly, you want the logo to animate upward when navigating away from home, but reappear fixed on the other pages?

Comment: actually It is not working. I am also newbie to jQuery So I am not getting any result.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It will be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    jQuery('h1#logo').css({
      top: '-85px'
    });
  }
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      jQuery('h1#logo').clearQueue();
      jQuery('h1#logo').animate({
        top: '-85px'
      });
    } else if(jQuery('h1#logo').position().top != 0) {
      jQuery('h1#logo').clearQueue();
      jQuery('h1#logo').animate({
        top: '0px'
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```